# Excel Calculate How Long An Item Has Appeared On A List

Tags: excel, list, formula, days

I have a list of items. The "RunDate" column has the days an item appeared on a list. I'm trying to find out how long an item appeared on a list. In my data example, OrderItemID 2758392 appeared for 3 days (RunDate) 1/4/2022, 1/5/2022 and 1/6/2022. Similarly, I want to calculate that for every OderItemID on my list. For example 3105260 appeared 3 days 24th, 25th, 26th.

```
Facility    OrderNo PartNumber  OrderItemsId    RunDate
CA      451335-00   125759-100  2758392       1/4/2022
CA      451335-00   125759-100  2758392       1/5/2022
CA      451335-00   125759-100  2758392       1/6/2022
CA      582422-00   100942-500  3105260       1/24/2022
CA      582422-00   100942-500  3105260       1/25/2022
CA      582422-00   100942-500  3105260       1/26/2022
CA      582422-00   100942-500  3105260       1/28/2022
CA      584448-00   105226-500  3121341       1/4/2022
CA      584448-00   105226-500  3121341       1/5/2022
CA      584448-00   105226-500  3121341       1/6/2022
CA      584448-00   105226-500  3121341       1/7/2022
CA      584448-00   105226-500  3121341       1/10/2022
```

Comment: [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to count how many times a certain Orderitemid appears in your list

[image]